# HashMap *_equiv methods - can't update by equivalent key

Tags: dictionary, rust

Current Rust's `std::collections::HashMap` contains three methods, `find_equiv`, `contains_key_equiv` and `pop_equiv`, which allow to query the map using some type "equivalent" to the type of keys. For example, it is possible to find a value by `&str` key in a map where keys are `String`s, `&str`s being "equivalent" to `String`.

However, there are no methods which allow to *update* the map using "equivalent" key. For example, there is no method like `get_mut()` which returns a mutable reference to the contained value.

Is there a particular reason why it is not possible or this is just a missing piece no one happened yet to add?

Comment: `get_mut` actually exists: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/collections/hashmap/struct.HashMap.html

Comment: @A.B. You're misparsing what he said—there is no method like `get_mut` for equivalent keys.

Comment: Given the presence of `find_equiv`, I would see no reason why a `find_mut_equiv` could not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is no one has implemented it. However, the whole `Equiv`/`_equiv` situation is regarded as a hack, and people aren't so keen about duplicating half of the `HashMap` interface to have `_equiv` methods. In future I'm sure we'll have a nice solution, but for now, we don't.

Comment: Would it be possible to specify a hasher/comparator that could be instantiated from a set of objects (instead of just the `Key`) and then produce a hash-value and be able to compare that inner object to `Key` ? The absence of overloading makes me thing the instantiation part might be tricky...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not sure what you mean. (`Equiv` is essentially a generalised `Eq` for different types, but asserts that two objects that have the same hash are also `.equiv`alent.)